# How should one do upper level method that returns self with python pep484 type checking

Tags: python, python-3.x, typechecking, mypy

How can one define a function in a class such that the return type of the function is the 'current class' - and not the base class. For example:

```
Class Parent:
   def set_common_properties_from_string( input : str ) -> <WHAT SHOULD BE HERE>
     # Do some stuff you want to do in all classes
     return self

Class Child( Parent ):
   pass

   def from_file( filename : str ) -> 'Child'
      return Child().set_common_properties_from_string() # The return type of set_common must be Child
```

Or should one cast it somehow? If the return type is baseclass, then it will give an error.

I know one could just drop it to two lines and add temporary variable for holding the Child(), but i think the one liner is much nicer looking.

I use mypy for type checking.

Comment: Just a style hint: spaces after and before parentheses make your code less readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the newly implemented (and still experimental) [generic self](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#generic-methods-and-generic-self) feature, which is a mechanism designed to help solve exactly the problem you're encountering.

Mypy supports the "generic self" feature as of [version 0.4.6](http://mypy-lang.blogspot.co.uk/2016/11/mypy-046-released.html) (note: the latest version of mypy as of time of writing is 0.470). Unfortunately, I don't remember off the top of my head if other PEP 484 compliant type checkers support this feature yet.

In short, what you need to do is create a new TypeVar, explicitly annotate your `self` variable to have that type, and also have that TypeVar be the return value.

So in your case, you'd need to modify your code to the following:

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', bound='Parent')

class Parent:
    def set_common_properties(self: T, input: str) -> T:
        # Do some stuff you want to do in all classes
        return self

class Child(Parent):
    def from_file(self, filename: str) -> 'Child':
        # More code here
        return Child().set_common_properties(...)
```

Note that we need to set our TypeVar to be bounded by the `Parent` class -- that way, within the `set_common_properties` method, we'd be able to call any other methods that live within `Parent`.

You can find a little more information on mypy's website and within PEP 484:

- http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#generic-methods-and-generic-self
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#annotating-instance-and-class-methods

Comment: In this case, I would use a name other than `T` for your `TypeVar` – uppercase letters e.g. `T`, `U`, `V` etc. are by convention placeholders for generic types, but since this `TypeVar` is explicitly bound to the `Parent` type, it will be less confusing if you name it something like, say, `ParentType` or somesuch. If users of your code see a `T` in there, they are likely to think it is a generic parameter, which in this case it is not.